# Why c++ does has not provided the ability to bundle multiple functions / class definitions under the same template declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I was writing code for a templated class and realised that for every function, we have to write template declaration for each member function while defining it.
Eg.

```
template <typename T>
class A {
  public:
    T func1();
    T func2();
};

template<typename T>
T A<T>::func1() {/* code */}
template<typename T>
T A<T>::func2() {/* code */}
```

Is there any specific reason that c++ does not provide functionality to write this with a syntax something like below :

```
template <typename T> { // start of Templated block
class A {
  public:
    T func1();
    T func2();
};

T A<T>::func1() {/* code */}
T A<T>::func2() {/* code */}
} // This closing brace marks the end of templated block. one template declaration for multiple definitions.
```

Comment: how would you know where the "templated block" stops?

Comment: I mean the pragmatic answer is probably "no one proposed it" since I don't think I've seen a proposal for it

Comment: Once you delve into rougher template waters, this will become really confusing.

Comment: This looks like a reasonable idea in your example. I don't feel very convinced that it will work well in all cases though. Nested templates, template classes with templated methods etc. You would have to mix the two at the very least, and that in itself could be confusing.

Comment: i dont think there can be any better answer than "Because thats how the rules are". That being said, i remember Bjarne telling stories from the very start of standardization and he said the comitee was very cautious with templates and on purpose made template syntax clumsy because at that time nobody was used to templates and what is unusual should have unusual syntax

Comment: "namespace template" could be an interesting idea...